# Name for inverse of heating or cooling rate?

Tags: thermodynamics, dimensional-analysis, units

I would call the average change in temperature of a body per unit time « cooling rate » or « heating rate » depending on the sign.  Is there a name for the inverse of this quantity, ie the time it takes for a unit change of temperature ?

Comment: Just cooling time

Comment: *Characteristic time* is also used for relative changes (e.g., the time it takes to eliminate, say,  half or $1-1/e=63\%$ of an initial temperature difference). Actual time relative to the characteristic time is sometimes called *nondimensionalized time* or *normalized time*.

Comment: Thanks, but both _cooling time_ and _characteristic time_ sound to me like times, not times per unit temperature.